# using bootstrap,ajax,jquery dynamically load content from certain part of url to container

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have idea:on the dashboard i have sidebar with ul and many li,each has different href attr.when i click on these li, #content will dynamically load from url of li,i try to use  ajax,but it will put many requests to server.see this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/a5e40935/8/)

and for the codes,pls refer `jsfiddle`

,pls open it in new window.
I wonder if it is impossible to do that with ajax?
any idea?

thanks.

Comment: Please write code what have you tried so far.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi   pls check it here ,https://jsfiddle.net/a5e40935/7/   ,updated.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a5e40935/8/   updated.  it loads file from local server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot load webpages that are from a different domain. This is known as a cross-origin request and they are blocked by any good browser so as to prevent [Cross-Site Scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks. This blocking is known as the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

If you look in your console when clicking one of the links in your fiddle, you will see the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

If you really need to show content from a 3rd-party site, you can try putting it into an [iFrame](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp). iFrames have their own limitations, but you should be able to accomplish what you want by using them.

**Note:** there is one exception to cross-origin requests. As you can see in the error message, there is a header missing. If you were able to change the code of the 3rd-party site to include that header when your site made the request, then you could load the 3rd-party site.

Comment: hi Matthew,actually i want to load content from local server html,this link is for demonstration only.so that means i can load content from local html with ajax?

Comment: Well, you need to show us real code man - otherwise impossible for us to help you.

Comment: @simonchou do you just not understand how to do it, or do you actually have a problem? Your code seems fine to me (other than the above problem)

Comment: this is almost the code i show in jsfiddle, the code from another link with # is  just content of modal window...

Comment: not fine,when i click these <li>s ,ajax will put many requests to server.one click ,one request,two clicks,4 requests.....etc

Comment: Really not sure what you're talking about - I just watched the network requests using the chrome extension "Live HTTP Headers" and I saw the proper number of requests.

Comment: pls click these <li>s from time to time,from one after another,then browser will become slow....

Comment: do you see that after you click among these li ,browsers will become slower and slower...and li will be added class : active again...it is very weird. i try to set variable **loaded** to 0 to activate ajax,then plus to 1 so next time ajax will not load ,but it is not working ...

Comment: Might be just your browser? I really have no problems at all.